# Why Apache benchmark results are inconstant?

Tags: apache, benchmarking

I run this command on ubuntu:
`./ab -n 2000 -c 10 http://localhost:7000/index.html`
and each time I get a different number for "Time per request".(huge difference like once is 0.66 ms next time is 0.17 ms).

Why is the result unstable and how can I measure the actual performance of the Apache server?

Comment: Perhaps there is other activity on the server? Try shutting down all unneeded services.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No heavy activity is going on, on the server.

Comment: What's the content of the page? Static HTML from a file on disk? PHP with hits to a remote database?

Comment: Just a plain text "It Works!", the original ab example.

Answer (score 1):

If just the first request is slower than the following and the next results tend to be faster than it´s very likely some kind of cache which speeds up the response. In the simplest case this is just the disk cache of the os.

If you´re benchmarking on a virtual machine you probably will not get very credible results:

http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-5581

[Benchmarking, Profiling on Virtual Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426933/benchmarking-profiling-on-virtual-machines)

Here some general best practices for benchmarking web servers:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html